# How to set a browser to browse from a VPN

Tags: vpn, browser

On my PC I am connected using a Cisco AnyConnect to my office VPN in another country.
In addition I am connected to the internet using a regular connection.

Is there a way to set my browser (chrome , ie) to browse from the other country (using the vpn connection)?
Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/304141/how-to-force-only-chrome-to-send-network-traffic-through-vpn-connection-on-windo

Comment: Thanks. In the proxy switchy network tab I dont see my VPN connection in the dropdown menu. Have you ever used it successfully?